# Getting a Custom Field Value on a Contact with Javascript API

Tags: custom-fields, api, javascript

I have a custom field for contacts that I would like to retrieve the value for using JavaScript.

Using the API explorer I have generated the code that does this. It works PERFECTLY from the API explorer (which uses PHP).

However, when I run the Javascript code in my extension I get an error. Here is the code:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'getvalue', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": ["custom_102"], //custom_fieldId
   "id": 2 // contact id
 }).done(function(result) {
   // do something
 });
```

Here is the error:

```
Object {
    invalid_field: Array[1],
    is_error: 1, 
    error_message: "field Array unset or not existing" } 
    error_message : "field Array unset or not existing"
    invalid_field : Array[1] 
         0 : "custom_102"
```

I am at a complete loss here... and would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect - and I just confirmed that the syntax generated by the API Explorer for Getvalue is incorrect, so you're not to blame!

The culprit is this line:

```
"return": ["custom_102"],
```

In JSON, the square brackets indicate an array.  "return" expects an array for a `Get` action, but `Getvalue` accepts only a single value (for the obvious reason).  If you remove the brackets:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'getvalue', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "return": "custom_102", //custom_fieldId
   "id": 2 // contact id
 }).done(function(result) {
   // do something
 });
```

You should be in business!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Would you say this is a bug with the api explorer code generation for Javascript?

Comment: I would - and I even looked at fixing it.  I realized that a) this is due to a slight inconsistency for "getvalue" in APIv3 that I imagine will be fixed in APIv4, and b) fixing it would basically require a specific hack for "return" on "getvalue".  I decided it wasn't worth it.  I'll ping Coleman on it though!

Comment: More like fixing an existing hack:
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8981